# Is it possible for a report viewer to export to excel and have the data export as numeric instead of text?

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I have a report that gets displayed in a report viewer. I would like to be able to export the report to excel and set the data which gets exported to show up as numeric instead of text.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean have the row/column that is numbers be formatted in excel as '*number*' instead of '*general*' upon exporting I would doubt it. Reason for this is because the Report doesn't save the Datatype, the designer does (the RD: tags in the report's definition are all for the report designer specifically and can be deleted without harm to the loading of reports) therefore, excel would have really no way of knowing if you wanted to have it formatted as a number or not.

I'm guessing there might be a way around this with excel macros or something but for simplicity's sake I am pretty certain it isn't possible.

(I would have posted this as a comment but for some reason you need 50 rep to post comments?)

Comment: Thanks for your input, I havn't been able to figure it out and so for now the user will just have to convert it to numeric through excel which is really easy I was just trying to do it programmatically so the user would not have to.

Comment: Yea, I'm having to do a lot of work arounds for stuff like that myself. Working on a work around for sorting since Interactive Sorting won't work with AsyncRender="false" it's a real bummer.

I hope I'm wrong and someone answers, but from what I've learned looking at the report schema I highly doubt there is a way, unless you do it manually and use the RD tags in the rdlc file.

Comment: I am not sure I know what you mean by sorting otherwise I would try and help.  If you are talking about sorting a data table maybe you could use LINQ to sort (asc, dec...) before entering into a table within a report.

Comment: Actually it's really simple just to send the data to a system.data.datatable and use the built in select() to filter and sort the data. It's just I have to make a UI for the user to supply what they want to filter/sort that's unfortunate. Easy but would be miles simpler if it just worked haha.